# Do points accumulated in mini games add up next time they start?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Between the mini games being active, can I save up to points I have earned? For example if I have 1100 points and don't claim a reward, would I start at 1100 the next time the games are happening?

Comment: I'm tempted to say no, because it wouldn't make sense to me if that was possible. I have no proof, nor experienced this since I either entirely missed the event or claimed the rewards when I participated... so I'll leave it at this for now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Points are not passed from one event to the next, no matter what you do.